# How can I group a pandas dataframe based on a string hierarchy?

Tags: python, pandas

Given a dataframe like this:

| Client | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Low |
| Client 1 | Medium |
| Client 2 | Low |
| Client 2 | High |
| Client 3 | Low |

I want to group by client and select the highest priority (Low, Medium, High) for each client. It should look something like this:

| Client | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| Client 1 | Medium |
| Client 2 | High |
| Client 3 | Low |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

convert `priority` into a categorical column before grouping:

```py
dtype = pd.CategoricalDtype(['High', 'Medium', 'Low'], ordered = True)

df['Priority'] = df.Priority.astype(dtype)

df.sort_values(['Client', 'Priority']).groupby('Client', sort = False).head(1)

     Client Priority
1  Client 1   Medium
3  Client 2     High
4  Client 3      Low
```

if you do not want to convert to category, you can map the positions instead:

```py
(df.assign(temp = df.Priority.map({'Low':3,'Medium':2, 'High':1}))
   .sort_values(['Client', 'temp'])
   .drop(columns='temp')
   .groupby('Client')
   .head(1)
)
     Client Priority
1  Client 1   Medium
3  Client 2     High
4  Client 3      Low
```

Comment: where's janitor? ;) +1

Comment: lol ... not needed here :)

Comment: You might add a note that categoricals are powerful, require less memory, but mean they you need to have exhaustive categories